# Переход между экранами

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigationcontroller

Пытаюсь осуществить переход из одного ViewController в другой ViewControllerTable. Переход прописываю в ViewController.m в отработке нажатия кнопки "Войти"(т.к. мне нужен переход только при выполнении условия)

```
ViewControllerTable *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerTable"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
```

Код не ругается, переход не срабатывает, Почему? Подозреваю, что это связано с Navigation Controller

## [image: storyboard]

[image: View Controller Table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установите `Navigation Controller` как `Initial View Controller`, в `IB` выберите вкладку `Attributes` и установите галочку `Is Initial View Controller`. В данный момент `Initial View Controller` у Вас `View Controller Connect` (На это указывает стрелочка в IB)